# How can I force the user to fill out a captcha after a specific number of failed login attempts with authlogic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, authlogic, brute-force

I'm trying to secure my rails 3 app against brute force login guessing. I'm using [authlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic). What's the best way to force a user (or bot) to fill out a captcha after a specific number of failed login attempts? Does authlogic have a built in mechanism for recording how many consecutive failed attempts came from the same ip? I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Authlogic has a **Authlogic::Session::BruteForceProtection** module (you can find how it's implemented [here](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/blob/master/lib/authlogic/session/brute_force_protection.rb)). Basically, it blocks an account after N unsuccessful logins. From its [documentation](http://yardoc.org/docs/binarylogic-authlogic/Authlogic/Session/BruteForceProtection):

> By default the
>   consecutive_failed_logins_limit
>   configuration option is set to 50, if
>   someone consecutively fails to login
>   after 50 attempts their account will
>   be suspended. This is a very liberal
>   number and at this point it should be
>   obvious that something is not right.
>   If you wish to lower this number just
>   set the configuration to a lower
>   number:

```
  class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base
    consecutive_failed_logins_limit 10   
  end
```

> In order to enable this field your
>   model MUST have a failed_login_count
>   (integer) field.

You could activate this module and add your captcha mechanism in the controller.

**Later edit**: I have just seen the 'from the same IP' part.

If you need a 'from the same IP' protection (i assume you mean that the attacker is not interested in a particular account, so the purpose is not to crack a particular account, but a [DOS attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack)), then in my opinion it shouldn't be done at this level (rails application server). This should be handled by your system administrator, on the front-end (proxy) server.

Comment: Note: You will still need to tell your app server that login failed, no?

My only suggestion is invoking `being_brute_force_protected?` when trying to log in manually. If set to true then render the capcha, set the limit to 3 attempts, and the lockout time for 1 millisecond.